# How can I make my background image not block out any existing widgets in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a tkinter project, where I set the background image (not a solid color). I was using .grid() for my widgets, but then I realized I need to display a widget at the very bottom of the tkinter window. To continue using grid for this, I separated my widgets into two frames; 1 frame that contained most of the widgets and one that just contained the widget I want to be displayed at the bottom. Then, I packed my frames, one on the top and the other at the bottom.

However, after I did this, my background image went on top of my existing widgets and blocked them out, so they can't be seen anymore. What can I do to fix this?

Here is the method I used to display the background photo:

```
from tkinter import *

filename = PhotoImage(file="image.png")
background_label = Label(root, image=filename)  # root is the Tk() object
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# Other code here

mainloop()
```

Comment: Call `background_label.lower()`.